# What (RC) battery plug is this?

Tags: batteries, connector, identification, plug

What type of plug is this? It belongs to a 7.2V 1600mAh RC car battery (NiMH I guess, 6*1.2V). Scanning the internet and comparing plug pictures, I came across similar plugs that go by "M-Plug" or "Mini 7.2 Connector" but I wasn't able to confirm this.

[image: photos of connector]

Comment: Kind of JST connector, measure the spacing between contacts and the search on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a Molex 5102 2 Pin connector.

Comment: That appears to be correct, thanks. I am wondering if they go by a different name in the RC community as I hardly found any RC batteries when searching with that plug name.